# filter array values with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In an angular json response as shown when stringified

```
console.log("point data "+JSON.stringify(res,data.data));
```

my json response is of this format

```
"Monday : meeting invite"
...
"Notice : Come to hall"
```

I am trying to iterate over the above list in view

```
$rootScope.allData = res.data.data;

<li ng-repeat="myData in allData ">

{{allData}} //prints Monday : meeting invite
</li>
```

how to do this upon iterating is a challenge

```
<li ng-repeat="myData in allData ">

  Today:   {{allData}} // to print "Monday"
  Task:   {{allData}} //to print meeting invite
    </li>
```

this is because the : represents a new data

Comment: Is your res.data.data array of string like this
"Monday : meeting invite" ... . Or is it a big string?

Comment: Pro tip: In the console, you can do this: `console.log('point data', res, data.data);` and it works beautifully, and is easier to type, and easier to read...

Comment: This would be _far easier_ to answer if you'd provide an [mcve].

Comment: @searcherforthetrueth yes it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elegant way with array functions

```
$rootScope.allData = res.data.data.map(function(dataItem) {
    const dataItemParts = dataItem.split(':').map(function(part){
        return part.trim();
    });

    return {
        head: dataItemParts[0],
        content: dataItemParts[1]
    }
})
```

And then

```
<li ng-repeat="myData in allData ">  
  Today:   {{myData.head}} // to print "Monday"
  Task:   {{myData.content}} //to print meeting invite
</li>
```

**For removing repeatable values with js you can use**

```
<li ng-repeat="myData in allData track by myData.head+myData.content">  
  Today:   {{myData.head}} // to print "Monday"
  Task:   {{myData.content}} //to print meeting invite
</li>
```

Comment: I have 5 items in the array but is prints in 25 times

Comment: Could you provide your array items contents?

Comment: Could your provide
console.log($rootScope.allData.length);
Or console.dir($rootScope.allData)?

Comment: Maybe the issue you are using ng-repeat inside ng-repeat. And then 5 * 5 = 25.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184288/discussion-between-searcherforthe-trueth-and-user10445503).

Answer (score 0):

On the data binding you can do split(':')

```
<li ng-repeat="myData in allData ">

Today:   {{allData.split(':')[0]}} // to print "Monday"
Task:   {{allData.split(':')[1].trim()}}} //to print meeting invite
</li>
```

The trim() is optional here.
This is not something I would do though. This gets the job done but what I would prefer is create/map the allData a new array of object having two properties. The heading and the task. Then access them while iterating.

```
// mappedData is mapped from allData
<li ng-repeat="data in mappedData track by data.Heading + data.Task">

Today:   {{data.Heading}} // to print "Monday"
Task:   {{data.Task}}} //to print meeting invite
</li>
```

**Update**: As per [user10445503](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10445503/) My code does need track by. Adding it to my code.

Comment: Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: myData in